# typedArray.hasValue() is returning true when It should return false

Tags: android

In my testing of retriving the `backgroundColor` of the attribute `<item name="android:colorBackground">#ff00</item>` from `styles.xml` I discovered that
if the attribute is not set in the `styles.xml` and I check for the attribute with `typedArray.hasValue()` it will still return true as if there is set some value and therefor I will never get the default value!

```
private void getBackgroundColor(){
    int[] colorAttrs = {android.R.attr.colorBackground, android.R.attr.strokeColor};
    TypedArray colors = context.obtainStyledAttributes(style, colorAttrs);

    if(colors.hasValue(0)){
        //it shouldn't come inside here because android.R.attr.colorBackground hasn't been set!
        //But it keeps retuning what looks like a white color.

        int backgroundColor = colors.getColor(0, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.defaultBackgroundColor));
    }

    colors.recycle();
}
```

Comment: Note: Changing `android.R.attr.colorBackground` to `android.R.attr.color` seems to get it to work with the correct behavior!

Comment: this is because `colorBackground` is assigned somewhere else in your current theme

Comment: @pskink Sounds like a possible theory. I will test that and if that is the case, then I will make my own custom attributes for this library instead of using the standard one which sounds like they are unpredictable

Comment: see `<sdk_root>/platforms/android-*/data/res/values/themes.xml` and find `<style name="Theme">` (its the first tag inside root `<resources>` tag)

Comment: and yes, custom attrs is the way you should follow